# Record Emacs interactive function invocations

Tags: key-bindings, interactive

I want to optimize my keybindings, in a way that the more a command invoked interactively, the more accessible will be a key-binding for it.

Is there a way to record all interactive function invocations (excluding insert would be nice) to a file?

Comment: See if this is what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9602640/5691066

Comment: Yes I can start from there.

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21323968/how-to-log-all-of-command-i-used-in-emacs